# Offset history for Kafka Topics and Consumer Groups

Tags: apache-kafka

I am interested in monitoring the consuming behavior. In particular, I would like to know when which messages were ready by which consumer group. Is there an offset or consumer history that I can access?

If it helps, I use Confluent Cloud for setting up the topics, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to know when events were processed by your consumer?

In that case, you should just add logging to your consumer code, then use a log-collection tool like Elasticsearch or Splunk like you'd use for tracking logs/history across any other services.